# TSQL: Track Employee Assignment by Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that returns the following table. Null indicates the employee is still in that assignment:

```
|Dept|EmployeeAssignment|BeginDate |EndDate   |
|1003|Analyst           |01/01/1990|02/04/2013|
|1002|Coordinator       |05/14/2000|06/01/2013|
|1003|Trainer           |07/28/2010|NULL      |
|1004|Janitor           |08/09/2013|NULL      |
|1005|IT                |09/02/2013|12/21/2013|
```

Is there anything I can do that would allow me to track if the employee was present in that assignment by month during 2013. Something like this would be ideal:

```
|Dept|EmployeeAssignment|BeginDate |EndDate   |Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|
|1003|Analyst           |01/01/1990|02/04/2013| 1 | 1 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|1002|Coordinator       |05/14/2000|06/01/2013| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|1003|Trainer           |07/28/2010|NULL      | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
|1004|Janitor           |08/09/2013|NULL      |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 
|1005|IT                |09/02/2013|12/21/2013|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: You're asking if we can return a different result set based on the output of a query, which you haven't provided. Also, you haven't provided any information about what you have tried so far. I wouldn't expect very much from SO until you improve your question. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't think the questions is to bad. Assume the first query output is the result of a subquery or CTE and we're of the races.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again you can extrapolate other months, but I think it clear to do this works.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/23003)

```
//using your demo input
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Dept INT,EmployeeAssignment VARCHAR(20),BeginDate DATE,EndDate DATE) 
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(1003,'Analyst'           ,'01/01/1990','02/04/2013')
,(1002,'Coordinator'       ,'05/14/2000','06/01/2013')
,(1003,'Trainer'           ,'07/28/2010',NULL      )
,(1004,'Janitor'           ,'08/09/2013',NULL      )
,(1005,'IT'                ,'09/02/2013','12/21/2013')

SELECT * 
      ,CASE WHEN BeginDate <= '2013-01-31' AND ISNULL(EndDate,GETDATE()) >='2013-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END Jan
      ,CASE WHEN BeginDate <= '2013-02-28' AND ISNULL(EndDate,GETDATE()) >='2013-02-01' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END Feb
 FROM @tbl
```